# how to display list and other labels in single page using sencha touch2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch2. i want to display some text labels below in that want display list. so i have define some labels and accessing twitter service it will give list of data. below is my code.

1. in this code if I comment the extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', if i used extend: 'Ext.navigation.View' then list data will display but wont display defined labels.
2. if I comment the extend: 'Ext.navigation.View', if i used extend: 'Ext.form.Panel' then list data wont display but it will display defined labels.

please tell me what is the problem in my code:

**Code:**

```
Ext.define("E:\SenchaTouch.view.Main", {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  //extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'companyprofilepage',
  id: 'companyprofile',
  config: { 
    items: [
    { 
      xtype: 'toolbar',
      docked: 'top',
      title: 'My Toolbar'
    },
    { 
      xtype: 'titlebar',
      title: 'Title name'
    },
    {
      margin: '10',
      xtype: 'label',
      html: 'Info1'
    },
    { 
      margin: '10',
      xtype: 'label',
      html: 'A company is a business organization. It is an association or collection of individual real '
    }, 
    {
      xtype: 'list',
      itemTpl: '{title}', 
      store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['from_user', 'text', 'profile_image_url'],
        proxy: {
          type: 'jsonp',
          url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Sencha Touch',
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results'
          }
        }
      },
      itemTpl: '<img src="{profile_image_url}" /><h2>{from_user}</h2><p>{text}</p>'
    }] 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only create Ext.Panel({}) and into these Panel can you put others Sencha elements. I hope help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `navigationview` and `panel` are set this config: `layout: 'card'` by default.

To have all your components display on single page, extend `Ext.Container` and add `layout: 'vbox'` to its config.

Hope it helps.